# Git crashed while executing checkout command

Tags: git, github, branch

I was updating all my git repo branches. The update was successful. But, somehow my system hanged while I tried to change the working branch. I was previously on `branch1` but when I tried to change it to `master` by `git checkout master`, the system hanged due to which I had to turn off my system.

Currently, the working branch is `branch1` only. But when I try doing `git checkout master` it gives the following error:

```
fatal: Unable to create '/home/ps/moodle/moodle_master/moodle/.git/index.lock': File exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

How can I resolve this without getting my repo damaged?

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions?

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I'm afraid to follow the instructions. I think what if I tried doing something on my own and the repo gets messed up.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: The file mentioned is empty. Should I just delete it?

Comment: Yes. <span>blah</span>

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I did that. But now, the `git status` is not clean. Should I use `git reset --hard`? . It's showing loads of files under "local changes made".

Comment: Did you actually make any of those changes? Did you make any changes you want to keep that you hadn't already committed? If not, then it's safe to `git reset HEAD --hard`.

Comment: What's in the index? Does it look like changes you intended to stage? Does the content in your working tree look like you what you expect your working tree to contain? (I suspect that you want to rebuild your index with `git reset` and that `git reset --hard` would be dangerous and wrong but only you know what things are supposed to be like.)

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Well, I recloned my whole repo again. As I mentioned in my question, the repo was updated correctly. No files were modified after that. But after all the updating procedures, when I tried to change the branch to master, my system hanged. So under every branch doing `git status` yielded over 100s of files. `git reset --hard` didn't help either. It was a good thing that I updated my Github repo.